# How to disable Binary Translator on the Android Emulator X86?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, dalvik

I am still getting warning requires library libhoudini by logcat, also i have compiled all library into arch x86.

On the Emulator without support Binary Translator - Log:

```
04-14 18:05:05.304: D/FFMpeg(992): ### Try to load lib: jniaudio
04-14 18:05:05.304: D/dalvikvm(992): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.app.test/lib/libjniaudio.so 0xa6a0d230
04-14 18:05:05.304: D/FFMpeg(992): Couldn't load lib: jniaudio - Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found
```

On the Emulator with installed support Binary Translator - Log:

```
04-14 18:05:05.304: D/FFMpeg(992): ### Try to load lib: jniaudio
04-14 19:34:00.764: D/dalvikvm(1171): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.app.test/lib/libjniaudio.so 0xa68cbd98
04-14 19:34:00.804: E/dalvikvm(1171): The lib may be ARM... trying to load it [/data/data/com.app.test/lib/libjniaudio.so] using houdini
04-14 19:34:00.808: D/houdini(1171): [1171] Loading library(version: 2.0.5.42475 RELEASE)... successfully.
04-14 19:34:00.808: E/dalvikvm(1171): dvm_dlopen: unable to open /data/data/com.app.test/lib/libjniaudio.so
```

Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

I can't load native libraries on my emulator, but system makes wrong for determining the target architecture  of shared library. I'd be grateful if someone could explain.?

**UPDATE 1.**

/obj/local/x86/libjniaudio.so - here header information of shared library.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          68664 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         32
  Section header string table index: 31
```

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Yep, just explain about your issue. I have tried to reminder what was my problem I think library was failed because of wrong address to driver's audio/video on platform android. Also this library audio worked on the only android-9, so i gave up and i have been to move out for using a some ready library like Vitamio.

Comment: So no problem, remember about 3 different versions. On the version of android 9, 10, 14 may have different drivers (linking to streaming a video/audio over driver). Android 5.0 may have again new other driver.

Answer (score 1):

are you 100% sure your library is an x86 binary ?

The binary translator shouldn't load up in this case.

You can check the real ABI of your files using readelf, file, or this Android app I've made: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app (x86 only for now)

Comment: Your app is nice!
I am sure using app with all libraries only x86. http://i.imgur.com/mdxcJQ8.png